# Convert and Convertback between double and "+" & " -" String

Tags: wpf

I would like to create WPF converter that converts double number to "+" or "-" String based on the number  Sign(positive or negative)
but I can't handle the converted back method because I don't have the number anymore.
The "+" and "-" signs bounded to a combobox at the xaml side
any ideas???

```
    public class AmountToDebitCreditConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value == null) || (System.Convert.ToDecimal(value) == 0))
            return string.Empty;

        return System.Convert.ToDecimal(value) > 0 ? "+" : "-";
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        KeyValue kv = value as KeyValue;

        if ((String)value == "+")
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Here's my Xaml code

```
    <igDP:UnboundField Name="ActualAdjustmentAmount" Label="PlusMinusKey"  Converter={StaticResource signConverter} >
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}"  LabelWidth="40" CellWidth="40">
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Flags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
                                            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                                            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Path=ActualAdjustmentAmount }" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings>
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:UnboundField>
```

Comment: Why do people do this to themselves...

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is not just to be able to use (and exploit) Converters, then I would rather suggest you to have a specific Sign property in your ViewModel and bind your view showing sign with that property.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to do this sort of conversion in a view-model whenever possible.

Nonetheless, you've pinpointed the problem -- you no longer have the number after your conversion. The fact is that you don't need to return a string from your converter -- you can return any object that will return the desired string from its `ToString()` override, and that object can contain any other data and behaviour that you want.

Here is a converter that should accomplish what you're after, though I haven't actually tested this:

```
  public class SignedDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return new DisplaySignedDouble(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      var d = value as DisplaySignedDouble;
      return (d == null || !d.Value.HasValue)
        ? 0d 
        : d.Value.Value;
    }

    private class DisplaySignedDouble
    {
      public DisplaySignedDouble(object value)
      {
        Value = value is double ? (double) value : (double?) null;
      }

      public double? Value { get; private set; }

      public override string ToString()
      {
        if (!Value.HasValue || Value.Value == 0d)
        {
          return string.Empty;
        }

        return Value.Value > 0 ? "+" : "-";
      }
    }
  }
```